# Отправка файла Telegram,Bitrix24, php

Tags: telegram, битрикс24

**Здравствуйте**, как мне получить файл из **Bitrix24** и отправить ботом в **Telegram**?
Беру файл из чата в битрикс методом `im.dialog.messages.get`, в ответ получаю массив с инфой последнего сообщения, в котором имеется ссылка на скачивание файла.

```
$result = CRest::call('im.dialog.messages.get',['DIALOG_ID' => 'chat###','LIMIT' => 1])['result']['files']['0']['urlDownload']
```

И отправляю его ботом в телеграм(в чат).

```
$response = array(
    'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
    'document' => $result); 
        
$ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $token . '/sendDocument');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Подскажите,что я делаю не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument), в document должна быть HTTP ссылка на файл.

Сервер, который хостит файл должен отдавать корректный MIME type.

Поддерживаются только gif, pdf and zip файлы.

Другой вариант - скачать файл c помощью PHP и отправить в POST multipart/form-data.

Comment: спасибо, помогло